# Elementor Testimonial Carousel not working properly ..?

Tags: wordpress, carousel, elementor, review, testimonials

Elementor Testimonial Carousel not working properly not showing slider dots and just show only one review I add 3 reviews but it only show one. and not other styling working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noFg1.png)

Elementor Testimonial Carousel not working properly not showing slider dots and just show only one review I add 3 reviews but it only show one. and not other styling working.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Check to see this problem may be caused by Loading JavaScript deferred. I have wp rocket for some caching. It's normally great but sometimes it can mess things up. If you do have a caching plugin or running a caching program somewhere on your server or site, check to see that that portion is turned off for that particular page that you are running ANY of your carousels.

Comment: Hello and congrats on your first post on SO! I believe this is very likely to be the answer to this question but wanted to note that a little formatting and some explanation as to why some system to deferr the scripts might cause an issue that would improve the answer for future searchers a lot :)